# How can I block the client from calling ajax function from console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, security

I'm working on a project and I've decided to execute submit forms with AJAX for multiple reasons and I have this function;

I've tried to call the `delete(someid)` function from the console of my browser and it worked; This is now a security concern;

How can I achieve this?

Below is a code snippet illustrating it:

```
function delete(someid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'delete',
        data: {
            id: 'someid'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on an HTML form to provide security for your API. Even if you could prevent the user from using their browser's developer console, they could still use PostMan or curl or any other HTTP client. If you expose an API (any API, including through regular form posts rather than Ajax requests), you should always assume that a skilled user can call those APIs at any time. Build proper security checks into the server, not the client.

Comment: Where is your `delete` called *in your own code*, can you show where you're using it?

Comment: "that worked which is now a security issue". Why is that a security issue? The server receives it in the same way as if it was triggered from the UI, or if it was triggered from outside the browser (e.g. using something like PostMan, or some C# code or something). It doesn't matter how the request happened, the **server** needs to be verifying that the request is acceptable before it decides to carry out the requested action. You can't rely on the client to provide security, because in the world of HTTP any client can simply be replaced by another one which doesn't implement the security.

Comment: hi guys .. so the security issue that i saw if that any user can call the delete function with any given id " and that function will delete a persone from a database with the given id "

Comment: @Ryadlaglagus Right. So what limits do you need to place on the user? What checks do need to perform to make sure that the currently logged in user is allowed to delete the indicated person from the database? Just move or copy that logic from the client to the server.

Comment: "if that any user can call the delete function with any given id " and that function will delete a persone from a database with the given id". Ok but that's not an issue specific to your browser, or to AJAX, or to the browser console. You could make that same request from **any** HTTP client (a browser is only one possible type of client...anyone can write some code to make a HTTP request in any programming language, even from the command-line). Again, you need to ensure that the server can check whether the client making the request is actually authorised to do so....

Comment: ...a typical ways to do that would include authenticating the user making the request - e.g. they have to provide credentials to identify themselves. If the credentials are invalid, you reject the request. If the credentials are valid, but the user is not someone with the right role in your application to delete users, you reject the request. If the user meets all the necessary criteria, only then can you allow it. But this is **always** the responsibility of the **server** to verify **all** incoming requests...

Comment: ...don't be tempted to employ "security by obscurity", whereby if there isn't a "Delete" button showing the in user interface, then you assume it's impossible to delete someone. That's just not how the web works, at all. You've already seen that it can be circumvented  - and using the console is just one way to do that. However you solution (disabling ajax from the console) is the wrong one that's all - not least because the console is only one of many ways to circumvent what the UI allows you to do. The correct and only viable solution is server-side security.

Comment: thank you guys you saved me ... one of the solutions that i found from what you said  is to attribute "authority" in sessions for users who can delete and check it in server side, and by this i make it sure that non admins cant delete thats the best solution... again guys thank you so much and execuse me im begginer in this a bit ... thanks alot <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to call the delete(someid) function from the console in the browser and that worked wich is now a security issue.

This isn't a security issue from the client side. As far as I know, there is no way to disable people from using the console to call javascript to be used against your API, and even if it is possible there would be over 100 different ways of getting around that.

For this, the security issue would be from your server/api side, and you should be checking requests before doing any sort of actual deleting with server side code.

> So the security issue that I saw if that any user can call the delete function with any given id " and that function will delete a persone from a database with the given id.

This would be a server side issue. You need to be doing some sort of authorization on the user. It's a pretty broad topic to answer in a single answer.

Generally the flow you would have, is the user makes a delete request to your server, the server would have some sort of information for the user sending the request (like an id), and the server would then check and see if the user with that id has the ability to delete users from the database.

Comment: thank you so much sir thats the solution.. to check in server side for authoritys